# How can I remove padding property from an element? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, media-queries, materialize

```
   <th style="padding-left:40px;" id="lbl_vehicleType"> 
     <h5> Vehicle Type </h5>
  </th>
```

How can I remove the `padding-left` with media query I tried using this approach.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        #drp_per_page2{
            color:red;
        }

        #lbl_vehicleType{
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }
```

I tried to change the color of the dropdown to see if it works.
    It did although the `padding-left` did not.
    I even tried making it `padding-left: -40px;` Still it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The only way an *inline* style rule can be *over-qualified*, using an *external* style rule, is by using the `!important` declaration, e.g:

```
#lbl_vehicleType{
   padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

For this reason, it's usually considered best practice to declare your styles externally *whenever possible*.

However, if it is not, using the `!important` declaration is the only method, as selector **weight** (i.e: using an `id` selector instead of a `class` selector) and selector *specificity* (i.e: being more *specific* with your selectors, .e.g: `table th#lbl_vehicleType`) will not be enough.

Consider the below for reference:

external styles (`style.css`) **<** internal styles (`<style></style>`) **<** inline styles (`style=""`)

**Side note**
On a side note, you can't use negative values (*percentage units* or *length units*) for the `padding` property.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add important tag if you want to remove anything from style if you want to achieve this with css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        #lbl_vehicleType{
            padding-left: 0!important;
        }
    }
```